# Making a subclass in Python which overrides superclass method

Tags: python, class, subclass

So I'm trying to make a class called Dean and this class has to be able to call upon the super class of say (just printing out a text). I was told to use Professor.say(self, stuff) to call upon the superclass of say but I don't really get that.

My code is as follows:

```
Class Dean(Professor):

    Professor.say(self, stuff)

    self.say(stuff + "- We need money now, send")
```

If it wasn't clear before, the whole point is to make it so that Dean says this for any instance of the superclass say, meaning even if there are other instances of say in subclasses (like the Lecturer or Professor in my other Python question) that it'll still say "- We need money now, send". Answers are appreciated but just tips on where I'm confused are just as good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try to rephrase what you have said using the correct terms. You want this subclass of `Professor`, called `Dean`, to have a method that overrides a method in its superclass; the method's name is `say`. The `Dean`'s method should call the superclass's version of the method.

The answer is: you define the overridden method the same way you defined the method in your superclass, using the same name and parameters. Inside that method, you can use the code you were told to use `Professor.say(self, stuff)` to call the superclass's version of the method before your subclass does whatever it needs to do.

Comment: Well rephrased. Classes, methods, Superclasses, ... all pretty abstract terms to grasp at first. I know *I* had trouble with it.

Comment: thanks sorry it wasn't clear to anyone who read it before i'll try to make it more so in the future.

Comment: @asdfaea: It took a couple of reads to figure out what you were asking, yes, but that's okay since you're newly learning this stuff. Just glad if I could help. Do apply the "homework" tag to your questions, though, if that's what they are -- I believe that it will make people more willing to overlook/help with basic confusion.

Comment: @Josh Caswell so i came up with this class Dean (Professor):
    def say(self,stuff):
        Professor.say(self, stuff)
        return self.say (stuff + "Give us money now yo!!!") cant hit enter in this thing if you need I'll put it in the question....but for some reason it runs on forever.....whenever i run the program....

Comment: Inside of an object's method, the object is referred to by the name `self`. So the code you have written calls an object's method named `say`, inside of that object's method named `say`. Think on that for a moment.

Comment: @Josh Caswell I ended up coming up with the answer so thanks for the help took me a bit but I figured it out thanks for everything.